# Logic App Blob Connector error with Skipped Dependent action

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am using a Blob Connector in my logic app to move files from FTP VM to Blob Storage. It works fine when files exists and are read in the SFTP Connector step previous to the Blob Connector.  But when the logic app runs and zero files are found. The Blob step fails with:

> {"code":"InvalidTemplate","message":"Unable to process template
>   language expressions for action 'rrbmingestblobconnector' at line '1'
>   and column '11':  'Template language expression cannot be evaluated:
>   the property 'outputs' cannot be selected.'."}

it seems that the Blob connector is try to read the outputs object when it does not exist.  I tried a condition checking for 'Succeeded' on the previous step but it did not help.

I would expect it would also get "Skipped" like the other steps that depend on the same step.

Little Help Please.

Wade

Comment: Well... Today the blob connector started respecting the skipped status of the previous steps.  maybe something was fixed overnight. :)

Comment: Was writing up a response and saw that.  Very strange - let us know if you see it again.